# Contar linhas com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um script no qual onde pego todos os emails de um *textarea*, enviando-os através de *Ajax* para outra página,esou utilizando o split para separar as linhas. No entanto, caso tenha 10 e-mails para enviar o *newslast* a cada 1s ele executa e envia linha por linha para meu Ajax.Desse modo, como posso contar as linhas que já foram enviadas ?

> Email Enviados: 0
>
> A cada linha que fosse enviada eu gostaria que esse contador
>   aumentasse em 1 subindo um por um ate chegar no final.

HTML

```
    <div id="env">

            <form>

                <textarea id="email" placeholder="email-da-pessoa@servidor.com"></textarea>
                <input type="button" id="execute" class="btn btn-success" value="Executar NewLast">

            </form>

            <hr>

            <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
              E-Mails Enviados: 01
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
              Enviado com sucesso para: luanlucas@outlook.com
            </div>

        </div><!--env-->


JS


    $("#execute").click(function(){

    var email = $("#email").val();
    var index = 0;
    splitemail = email.split("\n");

    splitemail.forEach(function(value){


        setTimeout(function(){

            $.ajax({
            url:'ajax.php',
            method:'GET',
            data: {
                email: value,
            }

            }).done(function(retorno){
                $("#ren").html(retorno);

            })

        }, 1000 * index)

        index = index + 1;
    })



});
```

Comment: Qual o escopo dentro de seu javascript da variável index é global? Porque no parâmetro de tempo do setTimeout multiplica 1000 milesegundos X index , para que isso? Se quer a contagem de linhas após o split é so usar: 

var qtd_linhas = splitemail.length;

Comment: faço assim pois aprendi dessa forma, tem algum problema no meu método utilizado ? assim costuma dar certo, pois ele envia a cada 1s um novo email nao envia todos de uma só vez o intuito é não sobrecarregar o sistema , tem algo errado com essa função ? obg pelas dicas, outra coisa por exemplo ja usei o split na var email ai quando tento da eplit na var index o cod simplesmente para

Comment: Vc tah fazendo errado o uso do setTimeout. Irá sobrecarregar seu sistema da mesma forma.

Answer (score 1):

Vejo os seguintes problemas no seu código:

**1. forEach**

O `forEach` não é uma boa, porque ele vai dar um *loop* sem esperar nada, ou seja, vai chamar os elementos da array de forma imediata sem fazer fila, executando tudo que estiver dentro de forma contínua e direta.

**2. SetTimeout**

Do jeito que colocou, vai chamar o Ajax a cada 1 segundo, mas não vai respeitar o processamento e irá mandar outra requisição após 1 segundo, e assim sucessivamente, podendo criar um gargalo no processamento do seu servidor.

### Sugestão

Crie uma função que irá enviar as requisições, e cada vez que o processamento do Ajax finalizar, você verifica se ainda existe e-mail na fila do array para ser enviado e chama novamente a mesma função. Cada vez que o Ajax é processado, você incrementa a variável `index` e joga o valor no `<span>` que criei como contador. Se eu for explicar cada alteração no código vai dar um texto enorme. Você pode ver diretamente o que foi melhorado e implementado no código:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="env">
   <form>
      <textarea id="email" placeholder="email-da-pessoa@servidor.com"></textarea>
      <input type="button" id="execute" onclick="envia()" class="btn btn-success" value="Executar NewLast">
   </form>
   <hr>
   <div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
     E-Mails Enviados: <span id="conta">0</span>
   </div>
   <div id="ren" class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
   </div>
</div><!--env-->
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var index = 0;
function envia(){
   var email = $("#email").val().trim();
   splitemail = email.split("\n");

   if(index < splitemail.length){

      $.ajax({
         url:'ajax.php',
         method:'GET',
         data: {
           email: splitemail[index],
         }
      }).done(function(retorno){
         index++;
         $("#ren").append('<br />'+retorno);
         $("#conta").html(index);
         setTimeout("envia()", 1000);
      });
   }
}
```

**No ajax.php, deve retornar algo assim:**

```
<?php
$email = $_GET['email'];
echo 'Enviado com sucesso para: '.$email;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou tentar dar uma explicação para você entender o que você fez, por suas respostas acredito que escreveu mas não compreendeu.

O **setTimeout** irá executar o código contido em sua função, que é um callback, apenas após o tempo configurado no segundo parâmetro dessa função no caso abaixo é de 3000 milissegundos que corresponde a 3 segundos.

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Portanto se defini o tempo como abaixo :

```
$("#execute").click(function(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var index = 0;
    splitemail = email.split("\n");
    splitemail.forEach(function(value){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.ajax({
                    url:'ajax.php',
                    method:'GET',
                    data: { email: value }
        }).done(function(retorno){
            $("#ren").html(retorno);
        })
    }, 1000 * index);
    index = index + 1;
});
```

está dizendo que é para enviar a requisição a cada 1000 milissegundos X index (1000 X index). Mas quem é index, index é uma variável contida no seu escopo local do evento **onclick** que é disparado quando há o clique sobre o botão em seu formulário definido pelo id **#execute**. A variável index é incrementada em +1 a cada interação do seu foreach que no caso é um loop  definido pela quantidade de itens contidos no seu array **splitemail**. Portanto, como a requisição ajax será invocada dependendo da quantidade de quebras de linhas contidas no seu textarea a cada interação do foreach vai multiplicar 1000 milissegundos por index, na primeira interação do loop o seu tempo será de 1000 x 0 uma vez que index é iniciado com zero, na segunda interação do loop setTimeout terá o parâmetro tempo de 1000 * 1 = 1 segundo (porque index é 1), e na terceira vez terá o parâmetro 1000 * 2 = 2 segundos, porque index será dois e assim por diante. Então portando não será 1 segundo como disse na sua pergunta e resposta ao meu comentário. A cada nova interação o tempo de envio vai gradativamente subindo porque está multiplicando index vezes 1 segundo.

Se setTimeout vai esperar o tempo definido no parâmetro  bastaria isso.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url:'ajax.php',
            method:'GET',
            data: { email: value }
    }).done(function(retorno){
       $("#ren").html(retorno);
    })
}, 1000);
```

Sua pergunta se refere como poderia contar a quantidade de itens já enviados. Na sua rotina você defini e variável index, a cada incremento do loop a variável é incrementada em mais 1. Portanto ao final da interação foreach de seu array o valor total de index será a quantidade de itens existentes em sua array **splitemail**. E se você quizer saber a quantidade total é como eu disse em comentário após o split do valor contido em seu textarea bastaria usar o lenght no array para obter as quantidade total de mensagens contidos na listagem.

```
/* Devolve a quantidade total de mensagens contidas no campo textarea
após transforma-las em uma array (uma lista) explodindo a string com o \n 
(quebra de linha) utilizando a função split */

var qtd_linhas = splitemail.length;
```

Montei esse exemplo imprimindo o valor do tempo em setTimeout para entender melhor.

[Teste Rotina Envio](https://jsfiddle.net/56b4vfj4/12/)

Insira emails com quebra de linha no textarea, e seguida clique em **RUN**:

Este exemplo seria o correto, com a quantidade de emails enviados exibindo em sua div.
[clique para testar](https://jsfiddle.net/56b4vfj4/16/)

```
$("#execute").click(function(){
     var email    = $("#email").val();
     var index    = 1;
     splitemail   = email.split("\n");  
     splitemail.forEach(function(value){ 
         alert("O tempo de espera é : "+(1000 * index));
         setTimeout(function(){ 
             alert(value); 
             $('#cnt_enviados').text("E-Mails Enviados: "+index); 
             index = index + 1;
         }, 1000);
     });
});
```